# How do i get answers from a radio input?

Tags: php, html

First off, I'm completely new to PHP, and have only done a bit of HTML/CSS before, so I don't know much about this stuff.

I've been given a task in school; To create something that uses:

1. Echo
2. A combination of HTML and PHP
3. Variables in PHP
4. Input

What I've been trying to make is a page, where you select which day it is today, press OK and a message will appear with the text: "Today is $today. There are therefore X days until friday.

What I've done so far:

```
    <p>
        Temporary description with HTML <?php echo "<p> and PHP. </p>" ?>
    </p>

    <?php


        $ledestreng1;  
        $ledestreng2;  
        $ledestreng3;

        $ledestreng1 = "Today is ";  
        $ledestreng2 = " There is therefore ";
        $ledestreng3 = " days until friday."  



    ?>



    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="day" value="monday"> Monday<br>
        <input type="radio" name="day" value="tuesday"> Tuesday<br>
        <input type="radio" name="day" value="wednesday"> Wednesday<br>
        <input type="radio" name="day" value="thursday"> Thursday<br>
        <input type="radio" name="day" value="friday"> Friday<br>
        <input type="radio" name="day" value="saturday"> Saturday<br>
        <input type="radio" name="day" value="sunday"> Sunday<br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
    </form>

    <?php
        if (isset($_POST[submit])){
        $today = $_POST[day];
        echo "<p>$ledestreng1 $today,$ledestreng2,$ledestreng3</p>";
        }     
      ?>
```

What do I do from here? How to i get the day chosen from the radio input, and how do I get it to say how many remaining days till friday? I'd think if-statements would work, like "if "Thursday" is chosen, there is "3" days untill it's friday."

Do you have any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: This is why you have a teacher. You could also try Google, being very basic stuff there are thousands, if not millions, of tutorials out there that deal with this.

Comment: I'd send the day as int, not as string. Then you can make a simple calculation to find the days left. (of course you'd have to add a little logic if selected day is "after" target-day (friday)

Comment: you realize that `<form>` defaults to GET if POST isn't implied. Then again, you're probably not reading comments or ignoring them; who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="day" value="monday"> Monday<br>
    <input type="radio" name="day" value="tuesday"> Tuesday<br>
    <input type="radio" name="day" value="wednesday"> Wednesday<br>
    <input type="radio" name="day" value="thursday"> Thursday<br>
    <input type="radio" name="day" value="friday"> Friday<br>
    <input type="radio" name="day" value="saturday"> Saturday<br>
    <input type="radio" name="day" value="sunday"> Sunday<br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $day = $_POST['day'];

    if($day == "saturday") {
      echo "6 days untill it's friday";
    } elseif($day == "sunday") {
      echo "5 days untill it's friday";
    } elseif($day == "monday") {
      echo "4 days untill it's friday";
    } elseif($day == "tuesday") {
        echo "3 days untill it's friday";
    } elseif($day == "wednesday") {
        echo "2 days untill it's friday";
    } elseif($day == "thursday") {
        echo "1 days untill it's friday";
    } elseif($day == "friday") {
        echo "Today friday";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was just what i was looking for :-)

Comment: can this answer be explained just a wee bit? rather than just dropping code.

Comment: ...I guess not.

Comment: I did not understand